# Converter HTML como imagem

Tags: c#, html, imagem, pdf

Possuo uma `string` com o HTML da página, há alguma maneira de salvá-la como uma imagem? Renderizar a página toda como uma imagem, e se possível, armazená-la em um `MemoryStream`.

Comment: Qual o objetivo de se fazer isso?

Comment: Preciso converte-lo para um PDF, eu tentei converter direto do HTML só que o iTextSharp n é compatível com todos os css utilizados, então pensei em converter o html para imagem e depois converter a imagem para PDF.

Comment: Veja se esse recurso online lhe ajuda [Converter HTML para PDF](https://convertio.co/pt/html-pdf/)

Answer (score 3):

### HtmlRenderer

É uma biblioteca em C#. Recomendo por que não precisa de nada a mais além da própria DLL, sem outras dependências, se quiser salvar em imagem.

**Exemplo** (retirado [daqui](https://amoghnatu.net/2013/05/13/converting-html-text-to-image-using-c/), em inglês):

```
namespace HtmlToBmpImageDemo
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
               Bitmap m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(400, 600);
               PointF point = new PointF(0, 0);
               SizeF maxSize = new System.Drawing.SizeF(500, 500);
               HtmlRenderer.HtmlRender.Render(Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap), 
                                              "<html><body><p>This is a shitty html code</p>"
                                              + "<p>This is another html line</p></body>", 
                                               point, maxSize);

               m_Bitmap.Save(@"C:\Test.bmp        }
     }
}
```

Também recomendo essa biblioteca pois eles tem suporte para salvar direto em *.pdf. Dá uma pesquisada no Nuget por `HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp`.

**Exemplo** (retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31944740/6241184), em inglês)

```
public static Byte[] PdfSharpConvert(String html)
{
    Byte[] res = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
        pdf.Save(ms);
        res = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return res;
}
```

### wkhtmltopdf

O wkhtmltopdf encapsula um aplicativo console para o .NET. Segundo a [página deles no GitHub](https://github.com/codaxy/wkhtmltopdf), é simples converter HTML para PDF usando a ferramenta.

Não vou entrar no assunto pois já existe uma resposta falando sobre ele.

Ele é protegido pelo [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html), então recomendo que dê uma lida, dependendo do seu caso, pode ser uma complicação. É claro que ler o "contrato" oficial da licença é fundamental, porém existem algumas ferramentas que podem te ajudar, como o [Choose a License](https://choosealicense.com/), que julgo bastante confiável. Outro fato curioso sobre o site é que [ele é *opensource*](https://github.com/github/choosealicense.com).

Comment: Então, eu já estava tentando fazer a conversão do html direto para o PDF, porém ele não carrega todos os CSS, pois não ha suporte a todos, ai o layout fica todo bagunçado.

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais fácil de você conseguir isto é utilizando um utilitário externo, no caso o [`WKHtmlToImage`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org).

Para tal, você vai precisar escrever o seu `HTML` em disco, usando o [`System.IO.File.WriteAllText(string path, string contents)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx).

O segundo passo é instanciar um [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx), setar o `processo.StartInfo.FileName` para o local onde se encontra o `WKHtmlToImage` e passar os devidos argumentos pelos `processo.StartInfo.FileName`

caso precise saber quais são os argumentos esperados pelo `WKHtmlToImage`, você pode consultar o [`Manual`](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html), apesar que no seu caso, acredito que `wkhtmltoimage <input file> <output file>` será o suficiente.

Quanto o processo finalizar, você poderá ler a imagem do disco.

Comment: Não haveria algum que eu pudesse salvar o html em uma string e depois converte-lo para uma imagem, sem que eu precise baixar?